# US visa run by entering Mexico?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-runs, irish-citizens

I'm in the US visiting family (from Ireland). My 90 days comes to an end in about a week. Can I cross the border (Tijuana), have lunch and return - getting my passport stamped, letting me stay for another 90 days?

Comment: How long do you actually intend to stay for in total?

Comment: I have stayed for around 80 days so far and I can only stay for 90, unless I leave - then I can come back. I would only go for the day and come back to the US after lunch.

Comment: No, I meant, how long do you intend for your time in the US to be in total (this visit+after re-entry)?

Comment: @user68871 Right. Do you plan to come back for another 90 days? You'll likely have a better shot of success at the border if you're coming back for a few days (or just to catch a flight) than if you're coming back for another 90 day stay.

Comment: @ZachLipton in my opinion you're still unlikely to have success even if coming back for only a day or two to catch a flight. When I have crossed back over the border with friends at or near the 90 days there has been a decent grilling and request for evidence of outgoing flight still within the 90 day limit. I have no experience of anyone past the 90 though. I live in Tijuana, Mexico.

Answer (score 23):

No. [Going to Mexico, Canada, and "adjacent islands" will not reset your 90 days](https://au.usembassy.gov/visas/visa-waiver-program/) (you can consult [a list of adjacent islands](https://www.ice.gov/sevis/travel)).

You can apply for a new 90 day period of admission by visiting a farther destination (say, Costa Rica) and returning to the US. However, such a move invites suspicion, and it's possible that you would be denied entry. The Visa Waiver Program is intended for temporary visits for business and tourism purposes, and long repeated visits will give the impression that you are instead living in the United States.

You could break your travel into segments, returning home (or going elsewhere) for some time before returning to the US, or, if your circumstances allow, apply for a US visa, which will allow stays up to six months at a time with the possibility of applying for an extension.